# Are launch vehicles or payloads transported through the Suez canal very often? Ever?

Tags: history, launch-vehicle, transport

There are some comments under [How do SpaceX intend to transport their starship/super heavy?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/53949/12102) referencing rockets in tight places including

> whatever you do, don't send it thru the Suez Canal :-)

referencing the [2021 Suez Canal obstruction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2021_Suez_Canal_obstruction) shown below in visible light and [SAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic-aperture_radar).

**Question:** Are launch vehicles or payloads transported through the Suez canal very often? Has this *ever* been done?

"Bonus points" for an composite image with a superheavy sideways properly scaled next to the [Ever Given](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ever_Given).

---

Related:

- [How are SRBs and solid rocket motors transported safely? Do they ever end up on trucks driven down public highways?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32630/12102)
- [Star-shaped artifacts in SAR images of the "Suez Canal traffic jam seen from space"](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/51087/12102))

[image: Container Ship 'Ever Given' stuck in the Suez Canal, Egypt - March 24th, 2021 cropped]

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Container_Ship_%27Ever_Given%27_stuck_in_the_Suez_Canal,_Egypt_-_March_24th,_2021_cropped.jpg) "Container Ship 'Ever Given' stuck in the Suez Canal, Egypt - March 24th, 2021"

[image: ESA multimedia via Wikimedia: Suez_Canal_traffic_jam_seen_from_space]

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Suez_Canal_traffic_jam_seen_from_space.jpg) and [original ESA source](https://www.esa.int/ESA_Multimedia/Images/2021/03/Suez_Canal_traffic_jam_seen_from_space)

> [...] The two identical Copernicus Sentinel-1 satellites carry radar instruments to provide an all-weather, day-and-night supply of imagery of Earth’s surface, making it ideal to monitor ship traffic.

Comment: Possibly the British rockets & missiles sent for testing & launch to Woomera in South Australia in from the 1950s to the early 1970s - Blue Steak, Black Knight, Black Arrow & the satellite Prospero. Also potentially acquired German V2 rockets after WW2, in the late 1940s. Interesting: [NY Times April 22, 1946](https://www.nytimes.com/1946/04/22/archives/british-rocket-tests-set-on-open-australian-plain.html).

Comment: On second thought, probably not, due to the Suez Crisis of 1956 & the closing of the canal from 1967 to 1975 as a result of the Six Day War in June 1967.

Comment: "[Skylark](https://galacticjourney.org/january-8-1965-the-skylark-of-space-britains-skylark-sounding-rocket/) components and payloads are made in the UK and then flown to Australia by transport planes. These include a special dedicated “explosives” transport plane that carries the rocket engines to Australia fully-loaded with their solid propellant. "

Comment: @Fred it looks like you've got a new answer to "How are SRBs and solid rocket motors transported safely?" linked in the question.

Comment: Interesting video of [Blue Streak](https://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/films/1951to1964/filmpage_rocket.htm) from the UK National Archives. Unfortunately it doesn't show how Blue Streak was shipped from London the South Australia.

Comment: @Fred oh no, I had something to do today; now after watching that I've gone off on a reading journey. Expect questions... :-)

Comment: Me too. I'm looking at V2s in Australia. They were sent there as deck cargo in 1947. I presume given that UK still controlled the Suez Canal in 1947 it would be reasonable to assume they traveled through the canal. [Fun at the fair?](https://www.abc.net.au/news/2017-09-29/the-nazi-rockets-that-travelled-down-under/8977048) & [this](https://www.v2rocket.com/start/others/point-cook.html). I think the Blue Streak video stated the shipping duration was 4 weeks. From non related research I know it took ships 4 weeks to travel from Naples to Australia via the Suez Canal.  ...

Comment: ... Going around Africa would have taken longer.

Comment: +10 for taking a cheap joke in my comment to the previous question and running full-tilt with it!